# Calling third party jar functions inside maven based spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I have an external jar file which I created from another project and use it inside a spring boot Rest API application.

I have tried installing, adding manually, importing it but I am unable to access the jar or unable to use it.

For eg. I have a jar called myjar.jar. If it is run on its own :

```
java -jar myjar.jar one two there
```

I would get my desired out put.

I want use this jar inside a Spring Boot Rest API application which takes in a json input and sends the input data to this and this jar gives the out put which is again returned in a json format.

But I am unable get this jar imported or be able to use it inside my Spring boot applications. Is there a way to access the functions/methods inside the jar file and call them.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: after build you have to upload your jar to your local repository. From that repository it will be downloaded and can be used.

Comment: I followed this document : https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/ which talks about installation and also updating the POM and I did that.  Also I use Eclipse. even after refresh/restart I still dont see that jar. Finally I created a lib folder and added the jar there but still unable to use it.

Comment: It is not necessary to upload that jar to local repository because when the application is shipped to a different system it will throw class not found exception  instead include that jar as a part of application. Did that link work for you?

Comment: What does "unable to access the jar or unable to use it" actually mean?

Comment: I want to use some of the methods inside that jar file. Import it and then use some inbuilt functions of that jar which I do not want to rewrite.

Comment: I'm utterly confused. Are you asking how to use a JAR as a library? That's Java 101, and literally the only thing you need to do is put it on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

You could put your jar inside your project and use its class and methods from built jar

Put myjar.jar inside project

```
/src/main/resources/libs-external/myjar.jar
```

Adding myjar.jar in pom dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>myjar</groupId>
    <artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/libs-external/myjar.jar</systemPath>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

Adding on build to use myjar.jar in spring application when building

```xml
    <build>
        <!-- exclude jars in resources to avoid duplicated libs on built classpath   -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/libs-external/*.jar</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Allow jar external on src/main/resources/**/libs-external/*.jar -->
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

packaging springboot app using myjar.jar like dependency

```
mvn clean install
```

This way you can use all class inside jar in your springboot rest app

The other way is using parent pom maven and working on modular projects.