# How to use spring boot application as dependency in existing springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to Spring-boot and I'm stuck on one of the problem.

**Problem Statement:**
We have an existing product which is written on top of java spring(maven, war package) and I cannot touch the source code of this application.
So to extend the feature of existing application(say adding additional api's), I want to write a spring-boot application(maven,jar) and add as dependency in existing application's pom.xml.

I want to know is it possible? if yes, please share the concept.

Comment: First a war can not be used as a usual dependency based on the structure of a war file. Furthermore even if you change the war to `jar` that will not work either because Spring Boot has particular way to create a jar which can not being consumed later as a usual dependency. If you can not touch the existing product you will not succeed at all. If you want to add supplemental API you have to change the original code (if you like to add REST endpoints only) you could go that path but must change the original project...

Comment: to be able to consume it correctly which means separate out the real code and the building of the final package (war, jar)...

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot touch the source code"? Have you talked to your boss about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot touch the source code"? Have you talked to your boss about this? - It's the product of other vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate application with the functionality you need and do a `clean install`. The next step is to call your new service as a dependency in the base application. To do this, do the following

configure this data with a new service (which you will call from the base one)
this should be written in the pom.xml of the new service at the top

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId> yourNewService </artifactId>
    <groupId> your.group.id </groupId>
    <version> 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT </version>
    <packaging> jar </packaging>
```

then trying to load your functionality from the base service as a dependency

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>yourNewService</artifactId>
            <version>${yourNewService.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried this but no luck. 
For example consider an existing application which has an api like /Employees and I have written extension for this say /Employees/1 and this extension is in separate spring project(can be jar to add as dependency in pom of parent pom.xml). After restarting server(tomcat) /Employees/1 not showing expected data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a built jar and wish import this jar into new spring-boot project try this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68011833/7505687

Don't forget to tell to new spring-boot project scan beans or configuration from imported jar

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68011833/7505687